# Django Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ofac'

Tags: python, django

I have an old project I have to work on. While running the project I got this `No module error`.

I am not running the project on a virtual environment. I am running it on my MAC. I am running Django 2 or more.

Please see below the image of the folder structure. Hope it helps.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/import_all_sdn.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ofac'
```

This is the code i want to run:

```
import csv, sys, os

# project_dir = "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/"
project_dir = "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/"
sys.path.append(project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='ofac.settings'

import django
django.setup()

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Add
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Alt
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn_Comments


file    = 'new_sdn.csv'
file1   = 'new_add.csv'
file2   ='new_alt.csv'
file3   ='new_sdn_comments.csv'

data = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=",")
for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.number = row[0]
        post.name = row[1]
        post.b_i=row[2]
        post.programe=row[3]
        post.more_info=row[4]
        post.vessel_call_sign=row[5]
        post.vessel_type=row[6]
        post.vessel_dwt=row[7]
        post.tonnage=row[8]
        post.vessel_flag=row[9]
        post.vessel_owner=row[10]
        post.dob_aka=row[11]
        post.save()

data1 = csv.reader(open(file1),delimiter=",")
for row in data1:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Add()
        post.number_id = row[0]  #am pus un _id la foreign key k asa stokeaza django foreign key-ul
        post.n = row[1]
        post.adresa=row[2]
        post.oras=row[3]
        post.stat=row[4]
        post.s=row[5]
        post.save()

data2 = csv.reader(open(file2),delimiter=",")
for row in data2:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Alt()
        post.number_id = row[0]
        post.ceva = row[1]
        post.aka=row[2]
        post.name_of_aka=row[3]
        post.a=row[4]
        post.save()

data3 = csv.reader(open(file3),delimiter=",")
for row in data3:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn_Comments()
        post.number_id = row[0]
        post.more_info = row[1]
        post.save()
```

Comment: You shouldn't post settings like `SECRET_KEY` on Stack Overflow. You’ve removed it from the question now, but it still appears in the question history, so make sure you change it before you deploy your project

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are adding the wrong directory to the project path. In order to use `ofac.settings`, you need to set the project directory to `Users/Dropbox/ofac_project` (the directory that contains `manage.py` and `ofac`.

```
project_dir = "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project"
sys.path.append(project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='ofac.settings'

import django
django.setup()
```